# Python : pass item from list two and that related to some items from list one?

Tags: python

how could i break (pass) item from list two that replated with list one if some condition exist??
ok here my code trying

```
numbers = ["1","2","5","3","4","9","6","5","7"]
mul = ["a","b"]
for num in numbers:
    for mul_nm in mul:
        h = num+mul_nm
        print(h)
        if (h == "5a"):
            print("don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers")
        else:
            continue
```

this program give this result :

```
1a
1b
2a
2b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
5b
3a
3b
4a
4b
9a
9b
6a
6b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
5b
7a
7b
```

while i need the process give this result :

```
1a
1b
2a
2b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
3a
3b
4a
4b
9a
9b
6a
6b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
7a
7b
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (from the example) - just move where the `print` is and modify your `if` condition to check for "5b" instead of "5a".

With these changes - the combination of `'num + mul'` will be printed unless the combination == `5b`, in which case the string warning will be printed.

```
numbers = ["1","2","5","3","4","9","6","5","7"]
mul = ["a","b"]
for num in numbers:
    for mul_nm in mul:
        h = num+mul_nm
        if (h == "5b"):
            print("don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers")
        else:
            print(h)
```

This produces your desired result:

```
1a
1b
2a
2b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
3a
3b
4a
4b
9a
9b
6a
6b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
7a
7b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `break`

```
numbers = ["1","2","5","3","4","9","6","5","7"]
mul = ["a","b"]
for num in numbers:
    for mul_nm in mul:
        h = num+mul_nm
        print(h)
        if (h == "5a"):
            print("don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Output

```
1a
1b
2a
2b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
3a
3b
4a
4b
9a
9b
6a
6b
5a
don't test 5 with b and pass to next item in list numbers
7a
7b
```